# Migrating from jcenter() to mavelCentral() issue in android

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter, maven-central

As you know Jfrog is going to shutdown `jcenter()` and we have to migrate from `jcenter()` to `mavencentral()` as [android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) mentioned.

I did it but after building the project i get the following error :

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3
Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
```

And when you click on the links you've get 404 error

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom

This is my `project level` build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       google()
   }
 }
 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: The 2nd link exists and works fine.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti none of them is working for me

Comment: Turn off gradle offline mode.

Comment: @sdex gradle offline mode is off already

Comment: Probably you have some issue with your network/firewall. The second link works fine. You can make sure by checking its status here: https://httpstatus.io/